# SupportMapFragment not showing Google Logo

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, supportmapfragment

I am using SupportMapFragment to display Google Maps in my app:

```
        SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (mMapFragment == null) {
        mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.map_frame, mMapFragment, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
    } 
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

This is the xml part:

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_status_view">

</FrameLayout>
```

Unfortunately, the map doesn't show the Google logo which causes violation on the Google Maps APIs terms of service (https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) In particular clause 9.4(a), which does not allow developers to delete or alter the Google logo on the map displayed in your app.

How can I add the Google logo to the map? Should it be there by default? Am I missing something? The fragment currently shows only the GPS button.

Comment: normally it shows by default at bottom left corner

Comment: Could you post your complete layout?

Answer (score 0):

use MapFragment instead of Frame Layout:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map" android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.googlemapdemo.MapsActivity"/>
```